# change range for multiple columns

Tags: r, range

I have to change the range 1-4 to 0-3 for five columns. (replace 1 with 0, replace 2 with 1,...). I already replaced those values for one column below. I still have to do the same for 9 other columns (AM01_02 - AM01_10).
How could I do this in a simpler way without using that much space?
Thanks a lot

```
#change range 1-4 to 0-3 
#replace 1 with 0
ba_data$AM01_01[ba_data$AM01_01  == 1] <- 0
#replace 2 with 1
ba_data$AM01_01[ba_data$AM01_01  == 2] <- 1
#replace 3 with 2
ba_data$AM01_01[ba_data$AM01_01  == 3] <- 2
#replace 4 with 3
ba_data$AM01_01[ba_data$AM01_01  == 4] <- 3
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R - Subtract the same value from multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65182275/r-subtract-the-same-value-from-multiple-columns) or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70794961/wanting-to-subtract-1-from-several-specific-columns-in-a-dataframe

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to Zheyuan Li's simpler method that works really well with math operations, this is a little more generalized for operations that might be a little more complex:

```r
cols_to_change <- c(2,4,5,8,10)
# or
cols_to_change <- c("AM01_01", "AM01_02", ...)

myfun <- function(z) z-1
ba_data[cols_to_change] <- lapply(ba_data[cols_to_change], myfun)
```

Walk-through:

- `lapply(L, F)` iterates the function `F` over each "element" in `L` (a list). In R, a `data.frame` is mostly just a `list` where each element (column) is the same length.
- Because `lapply(..)` returns a `list`, and the columns you're working on are likely a subset of the entire frame, we need to assign it back to the respective columns; ergo `ba_data[cols_to_change] <-`

The reason this is more general and can be useful: if your operation is more of a "lookup" than a "subtract one", you can change `myfun` to be more specific. For instance, if in all of these columns you need to replace `1` with `21`, `2` with `97`, and `3` with `-1`, *and leave all other values intact*, then you might write the function as:

```r
myfun <- function(z, lookup) {
  for (nm in names(lookup)) {
    z <- ifelse(as.character(z) == nm, lookup[[nm]], z)
  }
  z
}
ba_data[cols_to_change] <- 
  lapply(ba_data[cols_to_change],
         function(x) myfun(x, c("1"=21, "2"=97, "3"=-1)))
```

If you were to use a lookup like this, realize that I named them as **strings** regardless of what class the original data is, because "names" of things in R should not start with (or be entirely) numbers.

Comment: I've seen within a few seconds, but never the same time "exactly".